# Session id is not showing with an error message Notice: Undefined index: UserID

Tags: php, sql, html, mysqli, xampp

Session id is not showing with an error message Notice: Undefined index: UserID also if i redirect non logged in users i will not log into the home page iether.. here is my file could anyone please show me where i am going wrong.

here is the home page:

```
<?php 
require ("insert.php"); 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
}
else {
    echo "session not transferring";
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>AMSadler</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description of webpage">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords go here">
    <meta name="author" content="Anthony">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">

            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="AMSadler.com"/></a>
            </div>

            <div id="headertop">
                <div id="pagetitle">
                    <a href="home.php">HOME</a>
                </div>

                <div id="pagetitle2">
                    <a href="profile.php">PROFILE</a>
                </div>
                <div id="pagetitle3">
                    <h4>Welcome:<?php echo $_SESSION{"UserID"};?>to your page</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

            <div class="wrapper">

                <div class="leftsidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.php">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="main">
                    <div id="maintop">
                        <div id="textboxwrap">
                            <textarea name="text" id="styled"rows="5" cols="80" placeholder="Write something here.">
                            </textarea> 
                        </div>

                        <div id="postbutton">
                            <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="mainbottom1">
                        <div ="mainbottomwrap">
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="rightsidebar">
                    <div id="profilecontainer">
                        <img src="img/profile.png" alt="Upload a profile pic" title="profile pic" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="box">
                        <a href="#">blah</a><br>
                        <a href="#">blah</a><br>
                        <a href="#">blah</a><br>
                        <a href="#">blah</a><br>
                        <a href="#">blah</a><br>
                        <a href="#">blah</a><br>
                        <a href="#">blah</a><br>
                        <a href="#">blah</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

==================================================================
and here is the login page to get there.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<?php require ("insert.php"); ?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST[ 'Login' ]))
    {
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['email']);
    $pswrd= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['pswrd']);

    $result = $con->query (" select * from users where email='$email' AND pswrd='$pswrd' ");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["User ID"] = $row['UserID'];
    header ('Location: home.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>AMSadler login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description of webpage">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords go here">
    <meta name="author" content="Anthony">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="index" href="index.php">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="AMSadler.com"/></a>
            </div>

            <div id="signup">
                <button type="button"><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <form action="home.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
                <input id="Login" type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div id="copyright">
                <p>&copy Copyright 2015</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: their is a typo error.Their is space in `User ID` in the form page but no space in `UserID` on home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login page you're assigning the variable as this:

```
$_SESSION["User ID"] = $row['UserID'];
```

But on the home page you're looking for `UserID`.

Change:

```
$_SESSION["User ID"] = $row['UserID'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
```

The point you're getting your error from is from your usage in the HTML where you say:

```
<h4>Welcome:<?php echo $_SESSION{"UserID"};?>to your page</h4>
```

In the first instance you're using `isset()`, but here you're suddenly assuming it's there and ready for use. Either way you should edit the `User ID` variable, so this stops throwing an error. You might also want to add an `isset()` statement here.

P.S. Also heed Victor Perez's answer concering your password. And *don't* store them as plain text. You're literally just checking the `POST` password to the password in your database, that's no good. Also I might advice you to move away from using such query's and start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 2):

I sure hope you're just posting an example and that you're not storing plaintext password values...anyway...

I don't have enough reps to add a comment to @Bono, but in addition to his findings, you're also using the following POST:

```
$_POST ['pswrd']
```

But on your form, you have:

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Either the form name for the password needs to change or the POST you're looking for.